# asp.net5 selfhosted WebListener connection timeout

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using asp.net5 web project hosted in console app.
It works fine on localhost, but when i try to access this website form different machine like `http://192.168.1.5:5432` etc., i get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.
I was trying several arouches like chaning localhost to machine name but none of them works.

hosting.ini file:

```
server=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener
server.urls=http://localhost:5432
```

Is there any solution for this problem, or hosting in console app is only made for development purposes

Comment: Needless to say that port is open.

Comment: That's expected, because you have bound it to localhost, so it will only listen on connections to 127.0.0.1 or localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have bound your listener to localhost it will only accept connections to (and from) localhost. `localhost` is special here as it will (at least for Kestrel) always bind to localhost/loopback interface. Everything other than `localhost` binds to all network interfaces.

If you want it to be reachable by all IPs and be host/domain agnostic, you have to use `http://0.0.0.0:5432` (or alternatively `http://*:5432`). If you do `http://www.example.com:5432`, then it will be reachable from all IPs but only if the host name was typed in the browser so `http://192.168.1.5:5432` still won't work (unable to test the last one right now, but * wild card url should still work).

This way you can run multiple asp.net core applications on the same server but but with different hosts/domains.

You can also run two applications on the same domain and same port, if you bind them to different endpoints.

For example `http://www.example.com/App1` and `http://www.example.com/App2`, use same port and same domain but different endpoints and two applications.

**Edit**

Addition information for windows users. You may have to add an exception to the change the local security settings to allow dnx to bind to this port/host (or run it as Admin which would be discouraged), especially when using host and low-numbered ports (80 and 443 respectively).

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0:80
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/ user=Example\Username
```

This will allow applications for the user "Username" in the domain "Example" to start listening on port 80.