# Multiply listeners on same port (like virtual apps) with kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

The following will throw an exception that the endpoint is already being used:

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World 1");
        });
    }
}

public class Startup1
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string serverUrl = $"http://localhost:4000/test1/";

        var _webHost = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel()
                                        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                        .UseUrls(serverUrl)
                                         .UseIISIntegration()
                                        .Build();

        _webHost.Start();

        string serverUrl1 = $"http://localhost:4000/test2/";
        var _webHost1 = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel()
                                       .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                       .UseStartup<Startup1>()
                                       .UseIISIntegration()
                                       .UseUrls(serverUrl1)
                                       .Build();

        _webHost1.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error -4091 EADDRINUSE address already in use) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvException: Error -4091 EADDRINUSE address already in use
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.Check(Int32 statusCode)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvStreamHandle.Listen(Int32 backlog, Action`4 callback, Object state)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http.TcpListenerPrimary.CreateListenSocket()
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http.Listener.<>c.<StartAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http.ListenerPrimary.<StartAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelEngine.CreateServer(ServerAddress address)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
>          at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args)
>       Press any key to continue . . .

Is there any way to use different virtual paths to have two listerners on the same port like we could with owin and httplistener?

Comment: Did you try running this in two different applications? That should actually work, at least under windows. If you use low ports (<1024 or so) you need to add permissions with netsh, see second part of my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36575078/455493. Not sure if it worked with localhost, but for sure it works with named hosts and different applications  (i.e. www.example.com and editing the hosts file to route it to your ip/localhost)

Comment: based on the answer below i dont think its possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Kestrel doesn't support this. WebListener and IIS do though.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible / will it come later or is it simply not possible.  I wanted to run multiply applications in servicefabric on the same port.

Comment: It's not something we're planning to add. It would require a separate instance that owned the port and dispatched the requests like a reverse proxy. Try WebListener instead.

Comment: I want the new stuff :) thanks anyhow. I will look abit at reverse proxy options in service fabric, maybe thats they way to go

Answer (score 1):

I know this used to work with dnx when using hosts and different applications, so it should still works as it. The other alternative is to use `.UseWhen(context => ... )` within `Startup.Configure` method, as described in this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/conditional-middleware-in-aspnet-core).

```
public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.ToString().StartsWith("/test1"), testApp1 =>
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    });

    app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.ToString().StartsWith("/test2"), testApp1 =>
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    });
}


public static class AppExtensions {
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseWhen(this IApplicationBuilder app
        , Func<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext, bool> condition
        , Action<IApplicationBuilder> configuration)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        }

        if (condition == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(condition));
        }

        if (configuration == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        }

        var builder = app.New();
        configuration(builder);

        return app.Use(next => {
            builder.Run(next);

            var branch = builder.Build();

            return context => {
                if (condition(context))
                {
                    return branch(context);
                }

                return next(context);
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. This means that one has to be able to build one application with it all.  (I was going to use it for services in service fabric where i wanted each application to have its own lifecycle).